# FZF and NeoVim how to get files list

Tags: lua, neovim

I try to use neovim with fzf plugins. Part of my init.lua is

```
-- Plugin imstallation section                                                    
local install_path = fn.stdpath('data')..'/site/pack/paqs/opt/paq-nvim'           
                                                                                  
if fn.empty(fn.glob(install_path)) > 0 then                                       
  cmd('!git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/savq/paq-nvim.git '..install_path) 
end                                                                               
                                                                                  
-- Load the plugin manager                                                        
cmd 'packadd paq-nvim'                                                            
                                                                                  
-- Set the short hand                                                             
local plug = require('paq-nvim').paq                                              
                                                                                  
-- Make paq manage it self                                                        
plug {'savq/paq-nvim', opt=true}                                                  
plug {'scrooloose/nerdtree', opt=true}                                            
plug {'vim-airline/vim-airline', opt=true}                                        
plug {'vijaymarupudi/nvim-fzf', opt=false}                                        
plug {'ibhagwan/fzf-lua', opt=false}                                              
                                                                                  
require('paq-nvim').install()                                                     
require('paq-nvim').clean()
```

When I try to use command FzfLua files I observe message
fzf error 2 : unknown option: --headless

I work under Windows 10 and I use lua plugins : fzf-lua and nvim-fzf
fzf binary was installed and reachable

I cannot understand why rzr run with this strange option
What I did wrong?

Comment: this would be more suited for Vi and Vim stack exchange

Answer (score 1):

Fzf-lua uses `nvim-fzf` actions for previews (and other functions) which calls lua functions by running `neovim —headless … <lua function id>`.

It seems that your neovim version does not support the `headless` option, I know of other users running fzf-lua on WSL, try with the [official 0.5.1 appimage](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/download/stable/nvim.appimage)